# How to remove a certain number of duplicates from a list

Tags: flutter, dart, duplicates

I want to delete a certain number of duplicates from an ordered list in Dart. It could also be taken as the deletion of duplicates after a certain number of occurrences.
To illustrate my question, I will give an example, which could explain the problem much better than my words:

I want to keep 3 duplicates max. of each number or category.
This is what I am given:

```
[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]
```

Notice the occurrences per number. 3 and 4 are only present in the array one and two times correspondingly.

This is what I want that list to become:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5]
```

Comment: Is the list always sorted?

Answer (score 1):

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  var numbers = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5];
  const max_duplicates = 3;
  var base = numbers.toSet();
  var result = <int>[];

  base.forEach((number) {
    var counter = numbers.where((e) => e == number).length;
    result.addAll(List.filled(counter > max_duplicates ? max_duplicates : counter, number));
  });

  print(result);
}
```

Result:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var toRemove = [];
  var localScore = 10;
  var cuentaLocal = 0;
  filteredCareTakers.forEach((item) {
    if (localScore > item['score']) {
      localScore = item['score'];
      cuentaLocal = 0;
    } else if (localScore == item['score']) {
      if (cuentaLocal == 2) {
        toRemove.add(item);
      } else {
        cuentaLocal++;
      }
    }
  });
  filteredCareTakers.removeWhere((element) => toRemove.contains(element));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  final input = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5];
  final seen = <Object, int>{};
  var output = <Object>[];

  for (var e in input) {
    seen[e] = (seen[e] ?? 0) + 1;
    if (seen[e]! <= 3) output.add(e);
  }
  print(output);
}
```

or for the functional programmers:

```
void main() {
  final input = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5];
  final count = <Object, num>{};
  final output = input.where((e) {
    count[e] = (count[e] ?? 0) + 1;
    return count[e]! <= 3;
  }).toList();
  print(output);
}
```

I imagine you could do something with .fold and and a tuple, but that just seems like too much work. :)